# How to insert DBobject with TTL into MongoDB using Spring Java

Tags: spring, mongodb, ttl, mongo-java, spring-mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, I am trying to insert my db object using the below code, i am able to insert successfully but the DBobject is not removing after the given time it is still in db. Can any one give me example to insert the Dbobject correctly.

```
 BasicDBObject ttlIndexObj = new BasicDBObject("actionDate", 1);
 BasicDBObject ttlIndexObjOption = new BasicDBObject("name", 
 "actionDate_ttl_7_days").append("expireAfterSeconds", 204800);
  collection.createIndex(ttlIndexObj, ttlIndexObjOption);
```

Comment: It should be `collection.createIndex(...)` isn't it?

Comment: @pvpkiran I have updated my question.

Comment: what is the datatype of actionDate ?

Comment: @pvpkiran its a string, i have hard coded the value in the sample,

Comment: @pvpkiran do you have any java example

Comment: how are you saving objects to mongodb?

Comment: @pvpkiran using mongoTemplate() method

Comment: show the code. what is object that you are saving

Answer (score 0):

Do read the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#expiration-of-data). For TTL to work the indexed field has to be a `Date`.

And also the documents deleted may no be exactly after the times you specified. It may vary because the background task that removes expired documents runs every 60 seconds.